# Is Galaxy Apps a legimate App? (kitkat, samsung galaxy app 3)

Tags: samsung-apps, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

So on my samsung galaxy tab 3 running android kitkat, I noticed something in the notification bar. An app named samsung apps was downloading new apps, as if it was like the normal app store. One was Samsung billing.

After each download I was prompted, "Google may regularly check installed apps for potentially harmfull behaviour. Learn more in Google Settings > Verify apps."

It was followed by an accept and decline. I just pressed the back button and it went away. Then I noticee samsung apps was renamed Galaxy Apps.

Is this a legitimate new update? Did anyone else get this? (If you use a samsung device).

Answer (score 3):

[Galaxy Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_GALAXY_Apps) is the new name of Samsung Apps.

Samsung Billing is also legit, as per [Informer answer](http://answers.informer.com/94636/i-keep-having-an-app-on-my-phone-called-samsung-billing):

> The application is used to purchase apps through Samsung Store
>   application that is delivered with Samsung phones. Samsung Billing
>   acts as bridge between Samsung Store and payment servers. Without it,
>   you will not be able to purchase anything. It's safe to be removed
>   because it can be installed at a later date in case you actually need
>   it.

Comment: Is it a new update? My device has been connected to wifi for a while, so it only appearing now must mean its new?

Comment: @Keyes Updated sometime in July 2014. Maybe your Samsung store only checked /synced recently.

Comment: It also downloaded a "samsung IAP" if I remember correctly.  What is this?

Comment: @Keyes It's also legit. It's for In-App Purchases. See: http://developer.samsung.com/in-app-purchase